# using ImageDataGenerator, matplotlib throws TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 256, 256, 3) for image data

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

I have 15 images of cars, and using data augmentation, I want to create a dataset out of them. However, when I use `ImageDataGenerator` from Keras and try to plot the generated images, I'm getting an error that says

> TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 256, 256, 3) for image data.

I am attaching the code as well, please let me know how I can fix this.

```py
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, zoom_range=0.1, rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True)

ite = datagen.flow_from_directory("Car Images", batch_size=1)

for i in range(9):

    # define subplot
    plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)

    # generate batch of images
    batch = ite.next()

    # convert to unsigned integers for viewing
    image = batch[0].astype('uint8')

    # plot raw pixel data
    plt.imshow(image)

# show the figure
plt.show()
```

The error points to the `plt.imshow()` line.

[image: This is showing when I use np.squeeze() or np.reshape()]

Comment: You are passing image with batch dimension. Try to pass it like this: `plt.imshow(np.squeeze(image))`.

Comment: That works, but then for some reason every image shows as a black canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Invalid Shape` error, you should remove batch dimension. So, reshaping or using `np.squeeze()` is required.

Furthermore, since you are rescaling your images by `1./255`, images data are in range [0,1], and converting them to `uint8` makes all of them zero. So change your last 2 lines in `for` loop like this:

```
image = batch[0]                  #remove astype('uint8')
# plot raw pixel data
plt.imshow(np.squeeze(image))     #remove batch dimension
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reshape the image, try this.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, zoom_range=0.1, rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True)

ite = datagen.flow_from_directory("Car Images", batch_size=1)

for i in range(9):

    # define subplot
    plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)

    # generate batch of images
    batch = ite.next()

    # convert to unsigned integers for viewing
    image = batch[0].astype('uint8')

    image = np.reshape(256,256,3)

    # plot raw pixel data
    plt.imshow(image)

# show the figure
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is also showing only a black canvas for each image

I edited the question and attached an image to show what's happening when I try that.